# Тратится Промокод, не оплачивая товар

Tags: php, mysql

возникла проблема с сайтом и системой промокодов. Есть сайт, на нём человек вводит Промокод, нажимает Перейти к оплате, и сразу же возвращается обратно на сайт, не оплатив товар. Промокод тратится, даже не оплатив товар. Все данные так-же ещё хранятся в MySql. Также сайт связан с Free-Kassa. Вот код функции траты промокода:

```
function getPrice($promo, $price){
    global $mysqli; //глобальная переменная
    $raw = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM `promo` WHERE `promo` = '".$promo."'")->fetch_assoc(); //берём промокод из бд
    $discount = $raw['discount'];

    if($raw['count'] <= 0) return $price;
    if($raw['count'] == 1) $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `promo` WHERE promo = '".$promo."'");
    if($raw['count'] > 1) $mysqli->query("UPDATE `promo` SET `count` = `count` - 1 WHERE `promo` = '".$promo."' ");

    return $price = $price - (($price / 100) * $discount);

}
```

Может нужно перенести этот код в конец, когда уже проверяется оплата и всё остальное? А промокод ещё внести в ссылку, что-бы он проверялся и уже тогда удалялся\изменялся в БД? Так же код с начала оплаты:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
include "functions.php";

$row = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM `privileges` WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['group']."'");
$num = $row->num_rows;
if($num <= 0) die();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($row);
$nickname = urlencode(trim($_POST["nickname"]));
$donate = urlencode($row["name"]);
$price = getPrice(trim($_POST['promo']), $row["price"]);


if($config['mode'] == 1){
$order_id = rand(1000, 9999);
$merchant_id = $config['fk_merchant.id'];
$secret_word = $config['fk_secret.word'];
$sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$price.':'.$secret_word.':'.$order_id);
$mysqli->close();

header("Location: http://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php?m=$merchant_id&oa=$price&s=$sign&o=$order_id&us_nickname=$nickname&us_donate=$donate");
```

И код уже с проверки оплаты

```
$amount = $_REQUEST["AMOUNT"];
$intid = urldecode($_REQUEST["intid"]);
$email = urldecode($_REQUEST["P_EMAIL"]);
$order_id = urldecode($_REQUEST["MERCHANT_ORDER_ID"]);
$nickname = urldecode($_REQUEST["us_nickname"]);
$donate = urldecode($_REQUEST["us_donate"]);
$time = time();


$command = addslashes(getCommand($nickname, $amount, $donate));

$commands = explode(';', $command);


$mysqli->query ("INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `command`, `intid`,`email`,`nickname`,`amount`,`order_id`,`donate`, `status`, `time`)  VALUES (NULL, '$command', '$intid','$email','$nickname','$amount','$order_id','$donate', 0, '$time')");
```

Comment: про SQL-инъекции слышали?)

Comment: Никак нет, я почти ноль в этой сфере, и поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: Про SQL-инъекции: Если я в промокоде передам например что нибудь вроде `x' or 'y'='y` то ваш код вполне может посчитать это корректным промо и если вдруг не повезет, то сотрет все из таблицы промокодов.  _Никогда_ на подставляйте значения в текст запроса. _Всегда_ используйте подготовленные запросы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Кроме этого код транзакционно не безопасен. Если одновременно пройдут два запроса с одним промо, то может получиться, что вы прочитали поле `count`, в это время другой процесс уже его использовал (удалил запись), а вы спокойно перейдете к delete в итоге один промо можно будет использовать дважды.

Comment: По существу вопроса: структура БД не позволяет корректно работать с промокодами. Я бы сделал в таблице промо кодов id у записи. Если один и тот же промо можно использовать несколько раз, то клал бы в таблицу несколько записей с ним (и никакого поля `count`). В таблице с заказами добавил бы поле promo_id куда бы клал id использованного кода и контролировал бы уникальность этого поля (для не NULL значений). Проверка на наличие кода должна тогда возвращать id первого совпавшего кода для которого еще нет заказа.

Comment: И не важно, оплачен заказ или нет, если его создали, в БД код посадили, то можно смело говорить пользователю что код уже использован в другом заказе. Если он заказ еще не оплатил, то должна быть возможность его удалить (что бы потом использовать код в другом заказе)

Comment: Из таблицы промо в итоге никогда ничего удалять не надо. В БД должна оставаться история, для каких заказов какие коды были использованы.